# Calendar in row using React

Tags: reactjs, datatable, calendar

Can anybody help me to build a calendar using react js.
I would like to achieve generating calendar after selecting the month and the year.
The calendar table would be like this

[image: example]

Comment: what are you looking into, do you need help building a calendar or we need to build a calendar for you.

Comment: You have to try it yourself. We can only help after we've seen you try

Comment: Does https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/ or https://ant.design/components/date-picker/ help you? I am not sure what you actually want to archive, so maybe you could edit your question, please?